# Nested For Loops To Fill An Array

Tags: python, list, loops, combinations

I'm learning Python's nested loops but couldn't use nested loops to fill a list with the combinations. So far I have

```
for i in range(3):
   for j in range(3):
       paths = [i,j]
       print paths
```

When this prints I get:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 0]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
```

Which is a list of the possible combinations but if I try an extra for-loop to index them it doesn't seem to work and only gives the first element. I'm trying to get an array in the form:

```
Array = [[0,0], [0,1]... [2,2]]
```

where I can index said array and get `Array[0] == [0,0]` and so on.

Any hints on how to do this? I've tried for-loops and using the append function neither giving me the results I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the lists to the result:

```
result = []
for i in range(3):
   for j in range(3):
       paths = [i,j]
       result.append(paths)
       print paths

print result
```

This says: create a result list `[]` and append the `paths` value to it at each step. You'll then have a list of lists and you can access the first element as `result[0]` (which is indeed `[0, 0]`).

Answer (score 3):

I like [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)!

```
print [[x, y] for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]
```

But it creates three lists (the iterated two stay in memory) in python 2.7 which is the common one nowdays.

If you're using big values try this:

```
print [[x, y] for x in xrange(3) for y in xrange(3)]
```

which uses [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> combos = [list(x) for x in product(range(3), repeat=2)]
>>> combos
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
>>> combos[0]
[0, 0]
>>> combos[1]
[0, 1]
>>> combos[8]
[2, 2]
>>>
```

Note that this solution is also very flexible.  For example, if you want to find the combinations of the numbers one through five taken three at a time, all you need to do is change the numbers given to `range` and `repeat`:

```
combos = [list(x) for x in product(range(6), repeat=3)]
#                                        ^          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(range(3), range(3)))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

If you really need lists instead of tuples:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(range(3), range(3)))
>>> [list(t) for t in itertools.product(range(3), range(3))]
[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```